# Service Worker > Registration > Error > Scope Url should start with the given Script Url

Tags: ios, service-worker

1. OS: iOS 16.4
2. Failing code: navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js', { scope: '/' })
3. Service-Worker-Allowed: '/' header is set
4. Service Worker is hosted like: https://www.mywebsite.com/dist/app/service-worker.js
5. This error does not reproduce on Android 13 or Windows 10 (Chrome)
6. manifest scope set to "/"
7. manifest start_url set to "/dist/app/index.html"

Why is iOS throwing error "Scope Url should start with the given Script Url" when Android and Windows are fine?

I found Apple's source code for exception, but still can't figure what's wrong:

```
ResourceError ServiceWorkerJob::validateServiceWorkerResponse(const ServiceWorkerJobData& jobData, const ResourceResponse& response)
{
    // Extract a MIME type from the response's header list. If this MIME type (ignoring parameters) is not a JavaScript MIME type, then:
    if (!MIMETypeRegistry::isSupportedJavaScriptMIMEType(response.mimeType()))
        return { errorDomainWebKitInternal, 0, response.url(), "MIME Type is not a JavaScript MIME type"_s };

    auto serviceWorkerAllowed = response.httpHeaderField(HTTPHeaderName::ServiceWorkerAllowed);
    String maxScopeString;
    if (serviceWorkerAllowed.isNull()) {
        auto path = jobData.scriptURL.path();
        // Last part of the path is the script's filename.
        maxScopeString = path.left(path.reverseFind('/') + 1).toString();
    } else {
        auto maxScope = URL(jobData.scriptURL, serviceWorkerAllowed);
        if (SecurityOrigin::create(maxScope)->isSameOriginAs(SecurityOrigin::create(jobData.scriptURL)))
            maxScopeString = maxScope.path().toString();
    }

    auto scopeString = jobData.scopeURL.path();
    if (maxScopeString.isNull() || !scopeString.startsWith(maxScopeString))
        return { errorDomainWebKitInternal, 0, response.url(), "Scope URL should start with the given script URL"_s };

    return { };
}
```

UPDATE:
I probed the ServiceWorkerRegistration where it's successful on Windows 10 Chrome, and get the following:

1. Script URL: https://www.mywebsite.com/dist/app/service-worker.js
2. Scope: https://www.mywebsite.com/

I wish I could see what Script URL and Scope are being set to on iOS 16.4.

UPDATE 2:

I tried hardcoding script url and scope to the exact values that I probed from Chrome, and I continue to get the registration errors on iOS! I've tried with and without the trailing slash at the end of the scope. No good still.

Comment: Can you post an [mre] somewhere? Without that, I think it’s going to be difficult for anybody else here to help find an answer. And it’s possible that the cause here is an iOS/WebKit bug — but if so, it won’t be likely that any WebKit engineers will spend time looking into it unless there’s a reproducible example that they can test with.

Comment: @sideshowbarker just wanted to let you know the fault was mine entirely :) I posted the solution as an answer, but the problem was sending the "Service-Worker-Allowed" header twice. Each browser does things differently, so Chrome happily saw the "/" from one of the response headers and accepted it, but Safari on iOS I suppose either concatenates the headers into "/,/" and fails on that value, or it just flat out refuses to accept the headers at all due to its double presence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, solved!

**Actual problem**: Server was sending "Service-Worker-Allowed" header TWICE

**Solution**: Stop sending "Service-Worker-Allowed" header twice!

Verified that my service worker is finally showing Notifications when requested.